# Не работает стиль для элемента header__logo в css

Tags: css

```css
.header__logo {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color #fff;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__inner">
      <div class="header__logo">ARCANE</div>

      <nav class="nav">
        <a href="https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Jinx/Arcane">JINX</a> <br>
        <a href="https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Silco">SILKO</a> <br>
        <a href="https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Caitlyn">CAITLYN</a> <br>
        <a href="https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Vi">VI</a> <br>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стиль нужно подключить к вашей html странице. При такой структуре папок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

стиль подключается такой строкой:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Полный текст страницы:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header class="header">
<div class="container">
        <div class="header__inner">
<div class="header__logo">ARCANE</div>
            
            <nav class="nav">              
                   <a href="https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Jinx/Arcane">JINX</a> <br>
 <a href="https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Silco">SILKO</a> <br>
                <a href="https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Caitlyn">CAITLYN</a> <br>
                <a href="https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Vi">VI</a> <br>
 </nav>
        </div>

    </div> 
     
 </header>  

</body>
 
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как видите, все работает

Comment: Хотел начать корректировать. А оно само все исправилось. Спасибо за уделенное время и советы.

Answer (score 0):

В примере вопроса еть не закрытый тег `div`.
Так же не верно задан сам цвет в `css`.

Вот так все работает...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
.header__logo {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header__inner">
            <div class="header__logo">ARCANE</div>
                <nav class="nav">              
                    <a href="https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Jinx/Arcane">JINX</a> <br>
                    <a href="https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Silco">SILKO</a> <br>
                    <a href="https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Caitlyn">CAITLYN</a> <br>
                    <a href="https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Vi">VI</a> <br>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</header>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Хотел начать корректировать. А оно само все исправилось. Спасибо за уделенное время и советы.